# Is there a way to search ajax code for multiple words in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, google-chrome-extensions, jquery

There are various extensions in the Chrome Web Store that highlight multiple search strings in webpages e. g. Find Many Strings, MultiHighlighter or efTwo.

None of them seem to support searching in Ajax content, though.

For example:  using MultiHighlighter and running a search for zipcode (aka plz) `80331` on page http://www.basler.de/de/kundenservice/betreuer-suchen.html does not allow a search for `81675 80336 80639`. Not a single search term is highlited.

[image]

Is there any other software, extension or general fix to solve this task?

---

Further details:

Running Chromium Version 34.0.1847.116 on Ubuntu 12.10 (260972)

Link to extension "Find Many Strings" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-many-strings/phabnclfbnmhmoipebjdfhkiacojlcnc/details

Link to extension "MultiHighlighter"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multihighlighter/ocifbglmlbpgpbflnkfpclkmckoollbn

Link to extension "efTwo (F2)"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eftwo-f2-advanced-find-on/ccaikggmppdolhcehimngikgiafmdcep

Comment: Got some helpful feedback from the developer of "Find Many Strings".  It might be a bug with the highlighting jquery plugin ... http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: Got more feedback from the jquery plugin developer, how cool is that:  the plugin monitors the content it is run on, no further.  Developers of extensions could intercept DOM change events, remove prior highlights, and rerun the search. It's not complicated, just needs to be considered ...